# Vue.js - Configure a custom alias using WebPack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, alias

I am trying to create custom alias but I get an error:

```
Invalid options in vue.config.js: "resolve" is not allowed
```

This is what I did:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vue.config.js` is for *vue* configuration for *webpack* you need to wrap your `resolve` with either `configureWebpack` or `chainWebpack`, something like:

```
// vue.config.js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {...you config...}
  }
}
```

`configureWebpack` can be also a function, from the docs:

> If you need conditional behavior based on the environment, or want to
>   directly mutate the config, use a function (which will be lazy
>   evaluated after the env variables are set). The function receives the
>   resolved config as the argument. Inside the function, you can either
>   mutate the config directly, OR return an object which will be merged: